# Deploy Sharepoint Dashboad page and KPI List to other site

Tags: 2007, web-part, deployment

I have a report library in Sharepoint site where i have several dashboard pages. Each of these dashboard pages have kpi and excel web acess web parts in them (only out of box no custom web parts).

A KPI List based on excel data is also present in this site. The excel data is from an excel file stored in a trusted location ie a document library in the same site.

When i save this site as a template and create a new site collection based on this template my report library and dashboard pages , kpi list , docuemnt library are copied into the new site.

Problems are :

1)The web parts configured under each dashboard page are not displayed and i end up with a blank page .

2)KPI List references the excel file stored in my original site and not the excel file in the newly created site and gives excel services permission errors.

Is there a cleaner and better way of deployment than what i am doing now to rectiy these isues?